# When reassigning lambda, why called deleted copy assignment instead of move assignment?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I am implementing some sort of nested flat for_each (contrived example):

```
template <class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction flat_nested_for_each_of_sorts(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f) {
    while (first != last) {
        f = std::for_each(begin(*first), end(*first), std::move(f));
    }
    return f;
}
```

I want to return `f`, as it may be a struct with some data. But I want this function to work with lambdas as well. For example,

```
int example1() {
    int acc = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> values{{1,2},{3,4}};
    auto l = [&acc](int i) {acc += i;};
    l = flat_nested_for_each_of_sorts(begin(values), end(values), std::move(l));
    return acc;
}
```

Problem is, compiler don't like this code:

```
error: use of deleted function 'example1()::<lambda(int)>& example1()::<lambda(int)>::operator=(const example1()::<lambda(int)>&)'
```

I know that in this case copy assignment operator of lambda with captures is deleted. What I don't understand is why not call move assignment operator? If we are to write lambda "by hand", everything works fine:

```
struct Lambda_sustitution {
    int* acc;
    Lambda_sustitution() = default;
    Lambda_sustitution(int& acc) : acc{&acc} {}

    Lambda_sustitution(const Lambda_sustitution&) = delete;
    Lambda_sustitution& operator=(const Lambda_sustitution&) = delete;

    Lambda_sustitution(Lambda_sustitution&& s) {
        acc = s.acc;
        s.acc = nullptr;
    }
    
    Lambda_sustitution& operator=(Lambda_sustitution&& s) {
        acc = s.acc;
        s.acc = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    void operator()(int i) {*acc += i; };
};

int example2() {
    int acc = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> values{{1,2},{3,4}};
    Lambda_sustitution l{acc};
    l = flat_nested_for_each_of_sorts(begin(values), end(values), std::move(l));
    return *l.acc;
}
```

Compiler Explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/6Tb5WYqxj

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is why not call move assignment operator?

Because lambda doesn't have a move assignment operator either (and it does have a copy constructor).

---

In fact, you don't need to do any reassignments, you can simply do:

```cpp
template <class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction flat_nested_for_each_of_sorts(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f) {
    while (first != last) {
        std::for_each(begin(*first), end(*first), f);
        ++first;
    }
    return f;
}
```

And call it like:

```cpp
int example1() {
    int acc = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> values{{1,2},{3,4}};
    auto l = [&acc](int i) {acc += i;};
    flat_nested_for_each_of_sorts(begin(values), end(values), l);
    return acc;
}
```

---

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YvaceEE69)</kbd>